# Why does a CASE WHEN give me a different result to a WHERE with the same condition?

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I'm trying to use a case when and a pivot to filter some data, but get a result of a total count of 0, however, when I use the same condition in a where statement I get a result that's more what i expected.

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT FYEAR, 
    CASE WHEN (DIAG_3_01 IN ('E10','E11','E12','E13','E14','O24') OR DIAG_4_01 IN ('E232','N251','P702')) AND (OPERTN_3_01 IN ('N26','P22','X07','X09','X10','X11') OR OPERTN_4_01 IN ('Q011','X215','X216','X273','X121')) THEN 'a'
        ELSE 'Other' END AS 'Procs',
    (FCE)
FROM database
    ) AS a
    PIVOT(COUNT(FCE) FOR [Procs] IN ([a])) AS p;
```

So this results in a table with column name a and a row value of 0, whereas this code results in a total of about 4000:

```
SELECT COUNT(FCE) 
FROM database
WHERE (DIAG_3_01 IN ('E10','E11','E12','E13','E14','O24') OR DIAG_4_01 IN ('E232','N251','P702')) AND (OPERTN_3_01 IN ('N26','P22','X07','X09','X10','X11') OR OPERTN_4_01 IN ('Q011','X215','X216','X273','X121'));
```

Unfortunately I cant share the database contents, but would appreciate any insight as to why this might be happening.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn to create a [mcve]. By creating a small sample database with one table, a little bit of data and the smallest query possible that demonstrates the issue you a) better understand the problem, b) realise which part of the problem are actually key to seeing the problem and c) can then provide people you're asking for help an actual opportunity to run the code, see the problem themselves and tinker with it.

Answer (score 0):

The **CASE** statement is like an **If-statement**, which only returns the very first value it founds that meets the criteria. You can also check multiple cases with **WHEN** and if no criteria are met, then the query will show whatever is in the **ELSE** statement.

The **WHERE** clause is just filtering the result, meaning it tell the query which records should not be ignored.